# cakephp case insensitive login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm trying to make the usernames case *insensitive* but I still want to store the usernames in the same way they were registered. So if John were to log in, he would be able to type 'john' and his password.

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect');
        }
    }
}
```

Would I adapt the code above in some way or perform a custom SQL query?

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: just use the correct database collation and you will always have case insensitive queries, e.g. utf8_unicode_ci (ci stands for exactly this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means store the original "John" in database, then strtolower the database saved value, and the inputed name on the login form. Then you still have the same usernames the way they were registered.

Example Added:

Login.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register')));
echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array('label' => 'First Name:'));
echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('label' => 'Password', 'type' =>   'password', 'value' =>  false));
echo $this->Form->submit('Register');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Consider that when the user inputs there username and password. Say I am using the username "John". The capital J is what we want to make sure is in the database. We are not going to use strtolower when saving data. So by using a cake's save() method we can accomplish saving your case sensitive issue.

register.ctp

```
public function register()
{

    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       if ($this->User->User->saveAll($this->request->data)
       {
           $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account has been created', true));
           $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
       }}
```

Now when we do login action:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
 if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
       $logged = $this->User->query('Your sql query matching username/password with strtolower, if you need to implement security hash from cakephp you can do that through cakephp hash method');
     }
 }
```

Basic example but it should help

Comment: yes this is what I want to do but it's a matter of how with cakephp :(

Comment: @Tim I will post a small example to get you started

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strtolower` php function before saving it (or checking against it).

Comment: "but I still want to store the usernames in the same way they were registered"

Comment: Ok. My statement still applies ^_^

Comment: Please elaborate. If you `strtolower('John')` then only `john` will be saved into the database, not `John`.

Comment: @Jay "*[...] or checking against it*"

Comment: @Bracketworks That would require a custom SQL query, which isn't really the Cake way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

When you validate your login do something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(username) = '". strtolower($username)."'";
```

This will lowercase your column, username, and evaluate if it is equal to lowercase `$username`. That way, you can store anycase in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP does nothing with case sensitivity.  It builds a pretty generic query to check your entry against the username in the database.

```
$conditions = array(
    $model . '.' . $fields['username'] => $username,
    $model . '.' . $fields['password'] => $this->_password($password),
);
```

It's likely a database setting that is causing yours to be case sensitive.

On all of my sites, for example, my username is case insensitive, and I've done nothing special with code.

Comment: Has more to do with the collation than cake version, doesn't it?

Comment: @tigrang - likely yes - just like to always include what version I've tested on - even if it's pretty irrelevant, like in this case.  Bad habbit ;)

Comment: "CakePHP's Auth login is ALREADY case insensitive." is inaccurate, Cake doesn't do anything special to make it insensitive, it all about the collation. Cake just does a `'userfield' = 'exactlyWhatUserTyped'` ;)

Comment: @tigrang - good point- I shouldn't have worded it that way.  Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling $this->Auth->login(), add this line:

```
$this->request->data['User']['username'] = strtolower($this->request->data['User']['username']);
```

Simple!